# Inserting partial row with slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

Given:

```
case class User(id: Long, 
                first: Option[String],
                last: Option[String],
                email: Option[String],
                verified_at: Option[DateTime],
                created_at: DateTime)

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def firstName = column[Option[String]]("first_name")
  def lastName = column[Option[String]]("last_name")
  def email = column[Option[String]]("email")
  def verifiedAt = column[Option[DateTime]]("verified_at")
  def createdAt = column[DateTime]("created_at")
  def * = (id, firstName, lastName, email, verifiedAt, createdAt) <>(User.tupled, User.unapply)
}

val userQuery = TableQuery[Users]
```

where `created_at` is a mysql `TIMESTAMP` (i.e. it self-populates if not specified in the insert sql statement), I want to create an insert that omits `verified_at` and `created_at`. From the Slick 3.0.0 docs I gather that this should do the trick:

```
val insert = userQuery.map(u => (u.first,u.last,u.email))
  += (Some("Bob"), Some("Smith"), Some("bob@smith.com"))
```

IntelliJ is happy with this code and if I do a `insertStatement` on the map I get the expected insert statement:

```
insert into `user` (`first_name`,`last_name`,`email`)  values (?,?,?)
```

But on compile I get:

```
Error:(30, -1) Play 2 Compiler: 
 C:\proj\test\models\DBTableDefinitionsSpec.scala:30: Adapting argument list by creating a 3-tuple: this may not be what you want.
         signature: SimpleInsertActionComposer.+=(value: U): JdbcActionComponent.this.DriverAction[SimpleInsertActionComposer.this.SingleInsertResult,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Write]
   given arguments: Some("Bob"), Some("Smith"), Some("bob@smith.com")
```

Mind you this is just the statement preparation, it's not even related to the exectution. This is also already a reduced version -- I tried that same with the additional `returning userQuery.map(_.id)`, which had the same error, so it doesn't seem related to the primary key.

**Update:** This turns out it was a warning turned error. I've left an answer below in case someone else hits this issue.

Comment: I think u missed created_at in ur insert val insert = Users.map(u => (u.first,u.last,u.email,u.created_at))
  += (Some("Bob"), Some("Smith"), Some("bob@smith.com"),"{DateTime}")

Comment: Could you show us your table definition, so we can reproduce your error?

Comment: @aravindKrishna `created_at` is omitted on purpose, since I want the SQL to omit it, so that that mysql sets the timestamp. Which is why I'm using the `.map` rather than a `+= User(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually a warning. The project was based on an activator template which predefined a number of compiler options including:

```
"-Xfatal-warnings", // Fail the compilation if there are any warnings.
"-Xlint", // Enable recommended additional warnings.
"-Ywarn-adapted-args", // Warn if an argument list is modified to match the receiver.
```

While removal of `-Ywarn-adapted-args` ought to have solved it, it appears the warning gets emitted under 2.11 because of `-Xlint` regardless

There is a related ticked on the compiler marked as won't fix: "[unit insertion deprecation seems unavoidable in standard slick code](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8261)

That means that at this time you have to turn off either `-Xlint` or `-Xfatal-warnings` to make this code pass.

Answer (score 0):

In your `user entity` define like below mentioned.

```
def creation_at = column[Timestamp]("creation_at",SqlType("timestamp not null default 0")),
```

if u insert none at creation_at column , on table written as 0.

Comment: The problem was not related to the `created_at` timestamp, but due to compiler warnings. Once the warning was removed it inserted as intended with the timestamp being auto-populated by mysql as desired